# Отправлятся пустые формы

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго времени суток!

Есть таблица редактирование данных, удаление, добавление.
Помогите пожалуйста понять, куда вставить условие, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку отправки новой записи (в таблицу), ничего не происходило.

На данный момент, при пустых инпутах, в таблицу добавляется строка с пустыми данными. Requred в input не сработал.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var userData = [{

      name: 'Soaf',
      quantity: '3',
      price: '150',
    },
    {
      name: 'Cup',
      quantity: '10',
      price: '59',
    },
    {
      name: 'Chair',
      quantity: '2',
      price: '459',
    },
    {
      name: 'Table',
      quantity: '2',
      price: '19444',
    },
    {
      name: 'Bin',
      quantity: '2',
      price: '1843',
    },
    {
      name: 'Bear',
      quantity: '8',
      price: '3489',
    },
    {
      name: 'Phone',
      quantity: '4',
      price: '16843',
    }

  ];
  // Обновить таблицу в соответствии с данными
  var updateTable = function() {
    var dataTable = document.getElementById('table1'),
      tableHead = document.getElementById('table-head'),
      tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

    while (dataTable.firstChild) {
      dataTable.removeChild(dataTable.firstChild);
    }

    dataTable.appendChild(tableHead);

    for (var i = 0; i < userData.length; i++) {
      var tr = document.createElement('tr'),
        td0 = document.createElement('td'),
        td1 = document.createElement('td'),
        td2 = document.createElement('td'),
        td3 = document.createElement('td'),
        td4 = document.createElement('td'),
        btnDelete = document.createElement('input'),
        btnEdit = document.createElement('input');

      btnDelete.setAttribute('type', 'button');
      btnDelete.setAttribute('value', 'Delete');
      btnDelete.setAttribute('class', 'btnDelete');
      btnDelete.setAttribute('id', i);

      btnEdit.setAttribute('type', 'button');
      btnEdit.setAttribute('value', 'Edit');
      btnEdit.setAttribute('id', i);

      tr.appendChild(td0);
      tr.appendChild(td1);
      tr.appendChild(td2);
      tr.appendChild(td3);
      tr.appendChild(td4);

      td0.innerHTML = userData[i].name;
      td1.innerHTML = userData[i].quantity;
      td2.innerHTML = userData[i].price;
      td3.appendChild(btnEdit);
      td4.appendChild(btnDelete);


      btnDelete.onclick = (function() {
        return function() {
          if (confirm("Вы уверены что хотите удалить?")) {
            var deleteId = this.getAttribute('id');
            userData.splice(deleteId, 1);
            updateTable();
            refreshForm();
          }
        };
      })();

      btnEdit.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var editId = this.getAttribute('id');
        window.scrollTo({
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          behavior: 'smooth'
        });
        updateForm(editId);
      }, false);

      tbody.appendChild(tr);
    }
    dataTable.appendChild(tbody);
  }

  // Задаю форму для редактирования данных
  var updateForm = function(id) {
    console.log(userData[id].name);
    var quantityField = document.getElementById('quantity'),
      nameField = document.getElementById('name'),
      priceField = document.getElementById('price'),
      saveButton = document.getElementById('btnSave');

    quantityField.value = userData[id].quantity;
    nameField.value = userData[id].name;
    priceField.value = userData[id].price;
    saveButton.value = 'Update';
    saveButton.setAttribute('data-update', id);
  }

  // Сохраняю новые данные
  var saveData = function() {
    var
      newQuantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value,
      newName = document.getElementById('name').value,
      newprice = document.getElementById('price').value,
      datatoAdd = {
        quantity: newQuantity,
        name: newName,
        price: newprice
      };

    userData.push(datatoAdd);
    updateTable();
  }

  // Обновляю данные
  var updateData = function(id) {
    var
      upQuantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value,
      upName = document.getElementById('name').value,
      upprice = document.getElementById('price').value;

    userData[id].quantity = upQuantity;
    userData[id].name = upName;
    userData[id].price = upprice;
    updateTable();
  }

  // Обновить форму
  var refreshForm = function() {
    var
      quantityField = document.getElementById('quantity'),
      nameField = document.getElementById('name'),
      priceField = document.getElementById('price'),
      saveButton = document.getElementById('btnSave');

    quantityField.value = '';
    nameField.value = '';
    priceField.value = '';
    saveButton.value = 'add';
    saveButton.removeAttribute('data-update');
  }

  // Главные функции
  var init = function() {
    updateTable();
    var btnSave = document.getElementById('btnSave'),
      btnRefresh = document.getElementById('btnRefresh');

    btnSave.onclick = function() {
      if (btnSave.getAttribute('data-update')) {
        updateData(btnSave.getAttribute('data-update'));
      } else {
        saveData();
      }
      refreshForm();
    };

    btnRefresh.onclick = function() {
      refreshForm();
    };
  };

  init(); //Инициализация таблицы
})();
```

```html
<table class="table" id="table1">
  <thead id="table-head">
    <tr>
      <th class="table-th__name"><input onclick='sortTableName()' type="checkbox" id="stateInput3">
        <label for="stateInput3" class="arrows3"></label>Name</th>
      <th class="table-th__quantity">Quantity</th>
      <th class="table-th__price"> <input onclick='sortTable(2)' type="checkbox" id="stateInput2">
        <label for="stateInput2" class="arrows2"></label>Price</th>
      <th class="table-th__action">Action</th>
      <th class="table-th__none"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<div class="form-container">
  <form class="form">
    <input type="text" maxlength="15" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required />
    <input type="text" maxlength="15" id="quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" required />
    <input type="text" maxlength="15" id="price" name="price" placeholder="Price" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Add" id="btnSave" required />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы сами то видите хоть какую-то отправку на сервер?

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно убрать обработчик `onlick` с кнопки и добавить обработчик на форму(событие `onsubmit`) также не забудь прописать строчку `e.preventDefault()` в обработчике